# Linking to javadoc.io using Javadoc -link option

Tags: java, javadoc

I am trying to link into some Javadocs hosted at javadoc.io (specifically, PowerMock's Javadocs) using the `@link` option. I have tried to add the URL to PowerMock's Javadocs to my `-link` flag, but can't get Javadoc to recognize it. I am using external links to other Javadocs just fine (e.g. Guava, Java SE 7) with Gradle as my build system. I have tried the following options:

`-link http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/`

^ I have confirmed that there is a `package-list` file in this directory

`-link http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/`

`-link http://javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/`

`-link http://javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-core/`

All of these result in the following error (URL changed accordingly):

`javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/`

Does anyone have advice on how to make this work?

As far as I can tell this is some sort of javadoc.io specific problem, though likely a usage issue on my end - for example I am currently using `-link http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/` without issue, but `-link http://static.javadoc.io/junit/junit/4.12/` doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe running javadoc with the `-verbose` Option will give a hint, whats wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I still got nothing beyond:

`[ERROR] [system.err] javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/`

Comment: Accessing those URLs (`static.javadoc.io` versions) in a browser results in an access denied error. Javadoc probably has the same result.

Comment: Does Javadoc actually try to access the base URL? You can access [the package list file](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/package-list), [package summaries](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/org/powermock/core/package-summary.html), and [class files](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/1.6.3/org/powermock/core/ClassReplicaCreator.html) just fine.

Comment: I've emailed the javadoc.io contact people as well, was just hoping someone here would have experience since (AFAIK) javadoc.io is pretty standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the command line, use an argument like `-J-Dhttp.agent=javadoc`.

In Maven, use something like:

`<additionalJOption>-J-Dhttp.agent=maven-javadoc-plugin-${pom‌​.name}</additionalJO‌​ption>`

The background: As Danilo Pianini suggests in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513575/28465), the problem is the `User-Agent` header. However, the problem isn't an *empty* `User-Agent`; [it's the default Java `User-Agent`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506935), which looks something like "`Java/1.8.0_112`":

```
$ URL=https://static.javadoc.io/org.checkerframework/checker-qual/2.2.2/package-list

# default Java User-Agent:
$ wget -U Java/1.8.0_112 "$URL" 2>&1 | grep response
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

# no User-Agent:
$ wget -U '' "$URL" 2>&1 | grep response
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

# custom User-Agent:
$ wget -U javadoc "$URL" 2>&1 | grep response
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

So the fix is to tell Javadoc to use a different `User-Agent`. Java won't let you omit the `User-Agent`, so you'll have to provide a value, which Java will prepend to its default agent.

As best I can tell, the blocking of Javadoc isn't intentional: Javadoc just (probably unwisely) uses the default Java `User-Agent`, and the content delivery network that `javadoc.io` uses blocks that by default.

(One more note about Maven: Everything works fine with `-link`. It also works fine with `-linkoffline` if you download the `package-list` file and tell Javadoc to read it from disk. However, if you use `-linkoffline` but tell Javadoc to fetch `package-list` from the `javadoc.io` URL (this is an unusual thing to do), [it may fail](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-507). The problem: Maven tries to pre-validate the `package-list` file but, under some versions of Java, fails because it rejects the SSL certificate of `javadoc.io`, a certificate that Javadoc itself accepts.)

(Oh, and it appears to be important to use a URL specifically from `static.javadoc.io`, not `javadoc.io`. Also, I would recommend `https`, not `http`, in case `http://static.javadoc.io` someday starts issuing redirects to `https://static.javadoc.io`, as Javadoc [currently doesn't handle such redirects](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190312). Also, `https` is a good thing :))

Comment: A quick note to indicate that this mechanism of setting the `User-Agent` for `javadoc` to use no longer works in JDK 11.  I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing that `javadoc` probably no longer uses the `java.net.*` classes.

Comment: Slightly related bugs: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184969, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190312

Comment: For gradle 5 you need: `options.jFlags('-Dhttp.agent=gradle-javadoc')` (The single quotes are somehow important...)

Answer (score 5):

It's strange: I could see in the browser e.g. http://static.javadoc.io/org.pegdown/pegdown/1.6.0/package-list but when I add `http://static.javadoc.io/org.pegdown/pegdown/1.6.0` as javadoc's `link` option it says

> Error fetching URL: http://static.javadoc.io/org.pegdown/pegdown/1.6.0/package-list

I use next workaround:

1. With `maven-dependency-plugin` unapack the javadoc of desired dependency.
2. Link it with `linkoffline` option.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.8</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>unpack-javadoc</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>unpack</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <artifactItems>
                       <artifactItem>
                           <groupId>org.pegdown</groupId>
                           <artifactId>pegdown</artifactId>
                           <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                           <version>${pegdownVersion}</version>
                           <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/pegdown-javadoc</outputDirectory>
                       </artifactItem>
                   </artifactItems>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <links>
               <link>http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/</link>
           </links>
           <offlineLinks>
               <offlineLink>
                   <url>http://static.javadoc.io/org.pegdown/pegdown/${pegdownVersion}</url>
                   <location>${project.build.directory}/pegdown-javadoc</location>
               </offlineLink>
           </offlineLinks>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I have investigated the problem, the issue here is that a user agent must be set (an empty string is ok) in order for the connection to javadoc.io to complete successfully.

I worked the problem around and wrote [a Gradle plugin that may be of help](https://github.com/DanySK/javadoc.io-linker) for those who rely on that build system.

Unfortunately, the work around can not get ported to the regular `javadoc -link` command invocation.

Comment: That's awesome! Great work figuring out the root cause and working around it, Danilo.

Comment: Thanks!
By the way, I forgot a *not* in the last sentence: the workaround can *NOT* get ported to the regular command line invocation.

Comment: I got this to work with the default plugin by setting the system property that Java uses for `User-Agent` on the `javadoc` process. Note that this works only with `-link`, not `-linkoffline`, as Maven pre-validates `-linkoffline` `package-list` files, and `javadoc.io` appears to be rejecting _Maven's_ requests, too -- though seemingly based on something more than the `User-Agent` check it's using to reject `javadoc` itself. Anyway, the magic is `<additionalJOption>-J-Dhttp.agent=maven-javadoc-plugin-${pom.name}</additionalJOption>` (or whatever agent string you want to use).

Comment: Also, I should note that I don't _think_ `javadoc.io` is intentionally blocking `javadoc -link`. [This Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506935) suggests that blocking `Java/*` user agents is the default behavior for some content delivery networks, and `javadoc.io` and `javadoc` are just accidentally affected. Maybe `javadoc` itself should set a `User-Agent`....

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just using `-linkoffline` to get around this issue, which I suppose has the nice property of not needing internet connectivity at build time, though if anyone has further thoughts on how to make this work with `-link` I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

I am running javadoc.io.

This is reported as this [github issue](https://github.com/maxcellent/javadoc.io/issues/20) and it's solved just now. There is no need to override user agent string any more.

Feel free to re-open [github issue](https://github.com/maxcellent/javadoc.io/issues/20) if things are still not working. This thread is not actively monitored.

```
curl -I -A "Java/1.6.0_14" https://static.javadoc.io/org.checkerframework/checker-qual/2.2.2/package-list
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 13:06:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
```