# Set User Agent for javadoc tool

Tags: javadoc, user-agent

How can I set User Agent for the Javadoc tool in JDK 11?

As this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866209/linking-to-javadoc-io-using-javadoc-link-option/47891403#comment92714254_47891403) indicates, using `-J-Dhttp.agent=…` seems to no more take effect.

JDK 11 [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) states that `http.agent` should alter the behavior of “the java.net package”, and the `-J` option [hasn’t changed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javadoc.html). So, as the foregoing comment indicates, probably the javadoc tool has changed its way of accessing web content.

I tried to introduce a bug report about this, but I [can’t](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/).

Does anyone know how to change the user agent used by javadoc or how to ask that this feature be re-introduced?